# How to add shadow to text of a button in android?

Tags: java, android, button

I have a button with a png image as its background and i want to add a shadow to its text.

I have tried adding this code to button code in activity_main.xml:

```
android:shadowDy="20"
android:shadowDx="20"
android:shadowColor="#000"
android:shadowRadius="10"
```

but dosen't work.

**activity_mani.xml**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnMarket"
    style="@style/ButtonTheme"
    fontPath="bkoodak.ttf"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:text="@string/btnMarket"
    android:textSize="40sp" />
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="ButtonTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btnbackground</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">3dp</item>
</style>
```

Is that possible to add a shadow to text of button?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is

`yourButton.setShadowLayer(24,4,4,Color.RED);`

The structure of the method is like `setShadowLayer(float radius, float dx, float dy, int color)`

, dx and dy are x and y offsets of the shadow